# How to convert CSS into LESS when there are multiple classes using same properties

Tags: html, css, less

Here is my CSS. How can i convert this code into LESS format.

```
.A .B h4, .A .B h4 a, .A .C h4, .A .C h4 a, .D h4, .D h4 a 
{
    color: #345e8a !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: @font-family-sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty simple and straight-forward mate. What have you tried? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Also just in case we need to mention that it's already in Less format (no need to bulbulate selectors via nesting unless really necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS is just a CSS preprocessor, it's your selector that could do with the improvement, we can combine that with LESS namespacing to have something like:

```
.A, .D
{
    h4, a
    {
        color: #345e8a !important;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: @font-family-sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px !important;
    }
}
```

In the above I've simply stripped out your `.A .C` and `.A .B` selectors. If you need those, then you'll probably end up with an equally messy solution, but slightly more readable:

```
.A .B, .A .C, .D
{
    h4, a
    {
        color: #345e8a !important;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: @font-family-sans-serif;
         font-size: 17px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a bit incorrect, to produce the same CSS as in OP's example the nesting code would be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7f56b430b774ce20c34e#file-28045425-less).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yeah you're right, I assumed that the OP got his desired selector wrong, I took that `.D h4, .D h4 a ` should have been `.A .D h4, .A .D h4 a`. I've changed it to remove the assumption so it better reflects the actual question :)